# What would be the weight of the Tome of the Unicorn?

Tags: adnd-1e, adnd-2e, forgotten-realms

Given the dimensions of the book: "two feet broad by three feet in height, and over four inches thick", and being its pages made of "polished plates of electrum" (data from Forgotten Realms Campaign Set - DM's Sourcebook of the Realms, p. 92; TSR, 1987), what would be the weight of the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The density of electrum depends on the exact proportions of gold and silver, but ranges from around [12.5 g/cm³](http://www.sciences360.com/index.php/an-overview-of-the-precious-alloy-electrum-27485/) to about [16.5 g/cm³](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Electrum) †.

Assuming the book is effectively a solid made of electrum 24 × 36 × 4 inches, its volume would be 3,456 cubic inches. This is equal to [56,634 cm³](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2C456+inches+cubed+in+centimeters+cubed).

Given the density range above, this means it could weigh anything from 707 to 934 kg (1559 to 2059 lbs.). Based on our earlier assumption that the book is a solid, the actual weight would probably be a little less than that.

<sup>† The densities in the second source appears to have a minor magnitude error, in that 1,500 kg/m³ is impossibly light when electrum is composed of silver (~10,000 kg/m³) and gold (~20,000 kg/m³). If the digits are assumed to be correct, adjusting the magnitude to match that of silver and gold yields the sensible values of 15,000 kg/m³ and 16,500 kg/m³, which is 15g/cm³ and 16.5g/cm³.</sup>

Comment: There is a massive miscalculation here, as the density of Electrum varies between [12.5g/cm³ to 15g/cm³](http://www.sciences360.com/index.php/an-overview-of-the-precious-alloy-electrum-27485/), which is 1250kg/m³ to 1500kg/m³. "," in the site you quoted is not a decimal point.

Comment: Doh, my mistake. Thank you very much for the edit - I really should wear my glasses more often

Comment: @MrLemon One of those sources is wrong by an order of magnitude: [15g/cm³ is 15,000 kg/m³](https://www.google.ca/search?q=15+g%2Fcm3+in+kg%2Fm3), not 1,500, so they can't both be right. I just don't know which one.

Comment: Given that the densities of gold and silver are ~20g/cm³ and ~10g/cm³ respectively, I think ~15g/cm³ for electrum is the sane number. Which alters the calculation above considerably.

Comment: Wow, tough day for the math, I guess.  3,456 cubic inches is actually 56633 cubic cm, putting the weight more in the 680 kg to 900 kg range.

Comment: @Zimul8r It should be 2.23m³. At least, I'm going to trust that Wolfram Alpha (linked in the answer) got it right.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sorry, but in the link, you've typed "squared", not "cubed". Not to mention the fact that, online calculators aside, it's 3 ft by 2 ft by 4 inches, so it's well under 1 cubic meter.

Comment: @Zimul8r Ahahaha. So much math fail today. Thanks. That's why I included the link, to make sure the trail was followable. I'll fix that. This book is getting even heavier...

Comment: Yeah, although I suspect there's little practical difference between a half-ton book and a one ton book. Plus if it's got less than a dozen pages you're gonna need a friend to help you turn them...

Comment: @Zimul8r Details like this make me roll my eyes at the writer. Sure, a big book sounds awesome, as does a book with electrum pages, but clearly they didn't actually think hard about the implications of combining those two ideas before writing it down and calling it a day.

Comment: I don't know, Edison would have approved. http://books.google.com/books?id=7JDNAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22a%20hundred%20years%20from%20now%22&lr&as_drrb_is=b&as_minm_is=0&as_miny_is=1909&as_maxm_is=0&as_maxy_is=1910&as_brr=0&pg=PA299#v=onepage&q=%22a%20hundred%20years%20from%20now%22&f=false

Comment: @SevenSidedDie good catch. It didn't occur to me to look for even more errors.